# Why imap and write is faster than apply_async and write?

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-multiprocessing

imap version:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import timeit
import string
import random


PROCESSES = 5
FILE = 'test_imap.txt'



def remove_file():
    try:
        os.remove(FILE)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass


def produce(i):
    return [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(32)) for i in range(100000)]


def imap_version():
    with mp.Pool(PROCESSES) as p:
        with open(FILE, 'a') as fp:
            for lines in p.imap_unordered(produce, range(5)):
                for line in lines:
                    fp.write(line + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_file()
    imap_version_result = timeit.repeat("imap_version()", setup="from __main__ import imap_version", repeat=5, number=5)
    print('imap result:', imap_version_result)
```

apply_async version:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import timeit
import string
import random


PROCESSES = 5
FILE = 'test_apply.txt'



def remove_file():
    try:
        os.remove(FILE)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass


def produce():
    return [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(32)) for i in range(100000)]


def worker():
    lines = produce()
    with open(FILE, 'a') as fp:
        for line in lines:
            fp.write(line + '\n')


def apply_version():
    with mp.Pool(PROCESSES) as p:
        processes = []
        for i in range(5):
            processes.append(p.apply_async(worker))

        while True:
            if all((p.ready() for p in processes)):
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_file()
    apply_version_result = timeit.repeat("apply_version()", setup="from __main__ import apply_version", repeat=5, number=5)
    print('apply result', apply_version_result)
```

Results:

```
imap result: [62.71130559899029, 62.65627204600605, 62.534730065002805, 62.67373917000077, 62.74415319500258]
apply result [72.03727042900573, 72.17959955699916, 72.2304800950078, 72.02653418600676, 72.11620796499483]
```

I expected `imap` to be slower because child processes need to pickle the results to the main process and then write to file, whereas each child process in `apply_async` directly write the results to file. Instead, `imap` is slower than `apply_async`.

Why is this so?

nb: This was done using Python 3.4.3 on Mac OS X 10.11

Comment: Have you checked what the bottleneck is? Have you considered the downsides of resource contention?

Comment: FWIW, in my testing, the two scripts are only a few seconds apart (~28.5 seconds for the `imap` version, and ~31.5 for the `apply_async` version).

Comment: Also, adding a `time.sleep(0.4)` in your `while True` loop reduces the runtime of the `apply_async` version from ~31.5 to ~30 seconds. Try it on your system and see how much it improves performance. Doing that keeps your while loop from hogging CPU time from the workers.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath how do you check what the bottleneck is?

Comment: @nljson: that's your effort? Asking the same thing from me?

Comment: What? A busy loop?! Kill it with fire!

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance at your source code shows that the `imap_version()` opens your output file once per process where `apply_version()` opens it once per worker which is 5 times per process due to being inside your `range(5)` loop.

`with open(FILE, 'a') as fp` is called 125 times in your async version vs 25 times in your imap version.

Comment: I don't get it, how would that affect performance? Would you mind giving more explanation?

Comment: Your file IO is included in your timing function so it is skewing the results. Opening a file 5x more often will add a bit of overhead when you are trying to benchmark results.

Comment: So, does that mean I should stick to `imap` or are there any changes that might make `apply_async` version faster?

Comment: You can change the `apply_async` version to work the same way as the `imap` version by moving the file io into the `p in processes` loop instead of during the data generation process.

Comment: Do you mean using `apply_async` and calling `get` to send the result to main process and doing file I/O in it?

Comment: Exactly the same as `imap_apply()`. `with mp.Pool(PROCESSES) as p:`, open file, do your `apply_async` work, wait for results, write to file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the busy loop is the culprit (besides it being an anti-pattern in its own right).

By checking the state yourself, you do redundant work: `multiprocessing`'s machinery does pretty much the same with the work queue behind the scenes (in `multiprocessing.pool.Pool._handle_workers()` running in a separate thread). On the other hand, `IMapIterator.next` uses `threading.Condition(threading.Lock())` to suspend the main thread's execution until an item is ready (so `_handle_workers` runs unhindered - remember that only one thread can run Python code at each moment).

Anyway, this is but another guess. The only decisive evidence would be a [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html?highlight=profile#instant-user-s-manual) result.